# Is this definition of the Adjoint representation at group level only true for matrix lie algebras

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I have seen the Adjoint representation of a Lie *Group* be writted as:

$$Ad(g) = gXg^{-1}$$ for $g \in G, X \in L(G)$.

This makes intuitive sense to me if $X$ is in the space of matrix generators of the group G, but is it false in general for an abstract G?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an abstract Lie group $G$ and a group element $g\in G$, you may consider the conjugation with $g$: $$ \varphi_g:G\rightarrow G $$ which maps $h$ to $ghg^{-1}$. Note that $\varphi_g(1)=1$. If you take derivative at $1$ you get $D\varphi_g:L(G)\rightarrow L(G)$, which you call the adjoint action, i.e., $Ad(g)(X)=D\varphi_g(X)$.

If $G$ is not a matrix Lie group, it does not make much sense to write this as $Ad(g)(X)=gXg^{-1}$ since this notation implies that there is a way to multiply $g$ with $X$ from the left (similarly multiply with $g^{-1}$ from the right). For an abstract Lie group $G$, there is no meaningful map $L(G)\rightarrow L(G)$ which would constitute something like $X\mapsto gX$. Note that even in the matrix Lie group case multiplication from left does not preserve $L(G)$.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. In this case, if we want to define the adjoint of the Lie Algebra, do we have to resort to the definition of $ad = T_e Ad$ rather than D(gXg-1) ?

Comment: @AlexGower yes, that is how one defines the little adjoint action.

Comment: So it is still true (but only for matrix lie groups) that the little adjoint action can be defined by D(g X g^-1)?

Comment: @AlexGower yes, for a fixed $X\in L(G)$, if you actually calculate the derivative of the map $g\mapsto gXg^{-1}$ at $g=1$ you get the map $Y\mapsto [X,Y]=ad(X)(Y)$.

Comment: And does this make it clear that the lie bracket is only explicity a commutator for matrix lie algebras, since if you cant do $gXg^{-1}$ then ad(X)(Y) will not turn into a matrix commutator?

Comment: @AlexGower If $G$ is not a matrix Lie group, then the elements of $L(G)$ are not matrices. if $X,Y$ are not matrices then we cannot call $[X,Y]$ a matrix commutator. (It still satisfies some properties of a matrix commutator, though)

Comment: Okay, would [X,Y] still be a commutator of some object though, or would it in general be some different operation?

Comment: @AlexGower Not exactly, but its adjoint is a commutator, namely $ad([X,Y]) = ad(X)\circ ad(Y)-ad(Y)\circ ad(X)=[ad(X),ad(Y)]$ where the last commutator is indeed the usual commutator of two linear operators.